# Bilinear form respect to the representation $V/W$ of Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, bilinear-form

I got a problem from the book *An Introduction to Lie Groups and Lie Algebras* written by Kirillov.

The exercise 5.1 says
$$\begin{array}{l} \text { (1) Let } V \text { be a representation of } \mathfrak{g} \text { and } W \subset V \text { be a subrepresentation. Then } B_{V}=B_{W}+B_{V / W} \text { , } \\ \text { where } B_{V} \text { is defined by }(5.14) .\end{array}$$

and 5.14 says $$\text { Let } V \text { be a representation of g and define a bilinear form on g by } B_{V}(x, y)=\operatorname{tr}_{V}(\rho(x) \rho(y)).$$

I'm not sure what $B_{V/W}$ is. For $\rho_{V/W}(x)$, it should be defined as $\rho_{V/W}(x)(v+W)=\rho_V(x)(v)+W$. However, what should $\operatorname{tr}_{V/W}$ be? I can't find any information about this trace. Is there any common definition for it? Thank you.

Comment: Well, $V/W$ is a vector space isn't it? And $\rho_{V/W}(x)$ is a linear operator acting on it, so it has a trace...

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of $\rho_{V/W}$ is wrong.  $\rho_{V/W}$ is the representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V/W$ so it is $\rho_{V/W}(x)(v+W)=\rho_V(x)(v)+W$ for all $x\in\mathfrak{g}$ and all $v\in V$.  You can take trace of linear maps $V/W\to V/W$ so that gives you $\operatorname{tr}_{V/W}(\rho_{V/W}(x)\rho_{V/W}(y))$ which of course you can drop some of the $V/W$ subscripts for brevity.

Comment: thank you. I've fixed the typo.